# How can I assign Min and Max in the middle of a for loop using Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to work on a lab assignment for my Java programming class and have most of it done and working. This is the assignment:

> - Run a for loop that iterates 30 times. Use this loop
>
>   1. to compute `csMin` (the pennies value at day 21)
>   2. to compute `sumOfPennies` (the total of pennies from day 21 to day 30)
>   3. to compute `csMax` (the pennies at day 30)

This is basically part a converted Pennies for Pay problem where the pennies double themselves for every day worked. What I cannot figure out is how to get assign the value at day 21 to csMin. I think I have an idea on how to get the csMax and sum of pennies to work if I can just figure out the min part.

Here is what I have so far. I think you can kind of guess what I was trying to do but I wasn't sure myself.

```
for (int j = 1; j <=30; j++){  //j is there so the loop will count to 30

     //pennies are initalized to 0

     SumPen = pennies; //SumPen is the sum of all the pennies

     pennies = pennies * 2;

     for (j = 21){ /* I am getting an error saying ';' expected on this part*/

         csMin = pennies;

     }

     csMax = SumPen;


 }
```

Comment: I think you want `if (j == 21)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you basically have it, but the error you're getting is because you have a `for` instead of an `if` when checking the condition `j == 21`, which by the way is done with two equal signs.
Since you say you have an idea for csMax and the sumof pennies, I'll leave it at that, but feel free to ask if you have any problems.